# Best practice for objects where not all properties will always be used

Tags: java, oop, jsf

Here is my scenario:

I have an object with 10 properties (e.g. name, birthday, etc.).  I am using that object on two separate pages in my jsf web app.  On one page I will only ever use 5 of the properties, and on the other I will potentially use all 10.  What is the best practice / most efficient way to structure the object(s)?  Do I just have one object?  Do I have one object for the first page, and another for the second that extends the first object?  Or do I have an object for each page both extending a base object?

Comment: In JSF terms, you will likely have a managed bean per page, so every managed bean will have at least an instance of this object with 10 (or more) properties, then you will just use the properties needed in each view from your managed bean.

Comment: So it's true, interesting questions like this really do have no home on StackExchange :( - this would have been closed immediately on Programmers SE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't get too hung up on the properties, I'd think more about the class.

The class represents an atomic thing, right? Sounds like its a Person.

The fact that in some circumstances you're only using some of the properties, so what?

It makes no sense to have a HalfAPerson class!

So the key for me is the "atomicity" of your class in the first place. If if describes a single, logical thing, then why split it further?

Comment: this doesn't sound like an answer, but more a comment.

Comment: The absolute divide suggests some difference, its not "Sometimes 3, sometimes 10, sometimes 7" its "5, or upto 10". Suggesting its Class Person or class Employed Person or similar. In which case thats what inheritance is for

Comment: @Woot4Moo - amended answer to add a line in conclusion

Comment: @RichardTingle +1, fully agree with you with the caveat that the split is a sensible one

Comment: @RichardTingle I wouldn't say that's what inheritance is for at all. Employment status is a property/attribute of a person, not a different kind of person.

Comment: @MattDavey yes but you could envisage something like a Person class and an Employee class (which would inherit Person), something like that. Richard hasn't used a brilliant example but what he means is fine, surely?

Comment: You can never really say it represents an 'atomic' thing though.  Everything can be broken up further.  Yes, Person is a Person, and there is no half-person.  But there certainly is EmployedPerson and UnemployedPerson as Richard pointed out.

Comment: is that like saying its possible to split a hair???!

Comment: Not sure if that is a joke, but why not?  Hair has length and thickness properties.  DogHair and HumanHair are extensions.  Using this example for my situation, one page would use Hair, and the other page would use DogHair.

Comment: Its a common mistake to take the most important attributes in a given context and classify entities in those terms. In this context we deem employment status as the most important attribute, so we classify every person as either being employed or unemployed. This will often lead us to an entity which can **only** be used in the narrow confines of that context. What if our application grows and marital status becomes important, do we create 4 more classes, EmployedMarriedPerson, UnemployedUnmarriedPerson etc?

Comment: The person who coined the phrase "favour inheritance" was probably maintaining an object graph 3 miles wide...

Comment: ^^ sorry that's "favor composition over inheritance".

Comment: That is a fair point.  What is your approach then?  These examples are taking us down a slightly different path.  My scenario involves one object for one page, and another object for the second page the same as the first object but also has a few extra details.  So it would be like Person and MoreDetailedPerson.  Are you endorsing just having all properties in Person?

Comment: A class called MoreDetailedPerson doesn't sound particularly attractive. It doesn't really represent anything in real life. So yes, given this specific example, I'd lump everything into Person. Inheritance has a place sometimes but I don't think so in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this problem is as so:

```
package com.model  
public class MyClass  
{  
    //all 10 properties with getters and setters  
}
```

separate package for ui backing classes

```
package com.ui.backing  
public class FiveProperties  
{  
     private MyClass myClass;  
     //use the 5 properties here  
}      

public class TenProperties  
{  
     private MyClass myClass;  
     //use the 10 properties here  
}
```

The advantage of this is each page in your application is backed by a specific set of properties that you need.  It also enables the pages to have specific logic as opposed to duplicating code everywhere.

Comment: have to provide a comment if you are going to downvote.

Comment: I am agree with you, I wish there was a reason for downvote

Comment: Not sure why people downvoted this, but is pretty similar to what you must achieve with JSF. Note that your `FiveProperties` and `TenProperties` classes will be `@ManagedBean`s and possibly `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: You solution is creating some sort of reverse inheritance, starting with a base class that has all 10 properties then chopping some of them off

Comment: @RichardTingle have you ever worked with JSF to begin with?

Comment: @Woot4Moo I agree with this approach provided your FiveProperties and TenProperties represent tangible things, and are not just split arbitrarily or on the basis that one page needs all 10 properties and a second page only needs five.

Comment: @PeteH yes they would represent tangible things, it is hard to provide a full answer with the minimal amount of details we were provided.

Comment: In response to Luiggi - This is what I have right now.  Each of my two beans (five and ten) has 'MyClass' as a property.  But it seems like a waste in the one bean. Why not break MyClass up into two, with one either extending the other, or having the other as a member?

Comment: @RichardTingle not to endorse this answer, but the "reverse inheritance" you describe is often referred to as "specialisation via inheritance", where the root of the hierarchy contains all the behaviour, and derived types filter it to achieve their specialisation.

Comment: @bhouse then your problem is about how to design your entity classes. Yes, you can have a super class `Person` and a subclass `Employee` that extends `Person` (obviously with more attributes) and use each one independently in your managed beans, JSF will support it with no problems. The main thing here: is your application designed to support it?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule within all object orientated code:

If class A is like class B in every way but has some extra bits; class A should extend class B

If class A and class B are similar but neither are completely encapsulated by each other then they should both extend some base class.

I think you're in the first situation

Comment: I think your general rule is incorrect in most cases.  You want to favor composition over inheritance.

Comment: This doesn't apply on JSF real world apps.

Comment: This seems right to me.  In JSF I think it would look like this: Bean1 has Person property (Person has 5 properties).  Bean2 has EmployedPerson property (EmployedPerson extends Person and has 5 additional properties).  Composition is also an option, although in this example it would be a bit weird (EmployedPerson having Person as a property).

Comment: @bhouse: Based on your Person vs. EmployedPerson comment, could you just have all Persons with an Employment (and all its properties) status for the Person?

Comment: @splungebob: yes, but in my scenario you then have the one page that is using the person object, but completely ignoring all the employment properties.  The question kind of revolves around whether that is an okay practice or not.  Sounds like it might be okay in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if the pages are different you should use two different classes altogether as in the future you may not have any common attributes anymore.

Having said that, if you are using it across pages(maybe also storing it in the Session) with common data then I would suggest you to use a single object and use the appropriate number of attributes on the page.
This is with the assumption that those common values would be the same on both the pages.